# Javascript execCommand("copy") on Page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get javascript copy command working on page load.
I am able to copy it on individual user actions but not on page load.

I have read many blogs and it says it is possible only on user defined actions.

Is there any updated solution as of today to make it work on page load ?

Tried both the below approaches on page load; but no luck.
Kindly help.

```
document.execCommand("copy", false, null);

await navigator.clipboard.writeText("test");
```

Comment: The only update concerning `document.execCommand` is, that it has become obsolete.

Comment: As it clearly says on [the mozilla developer docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), `document.execCommand` _"[...] is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."_

Comment: Yes. Is there anything which I can use on page load ?

Comment: Using obsolete features is like you'd hit your head with a hammer, it causes pain later. Use [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) insead. Though what you want is not possible even with that API, because it's a security feature, you should not override the data on your users' clipboard without them knowing it.

Comment: Why would you ever need to copy on load?

Comment: @Teemu My query is simply asking for solution. I do know Clipboard API exists but its not yet compatible for safari iOS mobile. I am looking for solutions. By the way, in my case user is aware that text will be copied.

Comment: It's just not possible.

Comment: @Elias issue is we have multiple pages. User action is triggered from P1 which re-directs to P2 and then store.I don't have control on P1. I have control on P2 but P2 is for some other purpose. having said that, I want data in window location of P2 to be copied.